# How to consume NAV Dynamics WS in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, webservice-client, navision

I need to connect Navision to my PHP application. I have tried to use different ways that I have read in forums but none of them works. I don't know if I should use SOAP, cURL or other, could someone please guide me?

Edit:

I have tried the following code and it does not work either.

```
$opts = array(
'http' => array(
    'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
)
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$client = new SoapClient('http://URL:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/COMPANY/Page/mypage?wsdl/', ['trace' => 1, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'stream_context' => $context ,'user_agent' => 'USERAG', 'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2]);
$security = array(
    'UserName' => array(
        'UserName'=>'COMPANY\MYUSER',
        'Password'=>'mypass',
    )
);
$client->__getLastResponse();
$header = new SoapHeader('ChannelFactory','Credentials',$security, false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$checkVatParameters = array(
    'level' => '01');

$result = $client->checkVat($checkVatParameters);
print_r($result);

try {
    $ret = $client->getAllItm();
    print_r($ret);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from myurl**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code. A quick Google Search brought [this](https://stoneridgesoftware.com/connecting-to-dynamics-nav-web-services-using-php/) as first result. Please read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6273251) for info on how much research effort is expected of you when asking a question here

Comment: Before I asked I did a lot of googling. At the moment I don't have a fixed code as I have tried different ways (including the one you send me). Above all, I need to know what to use, i've tried SOAP, NTMLSoap, cURL... :(

Comment: At least tell which version of Nav are you using.

Comment: This one is old but should still work https://stackoverflow.com/a/25357700/1820340 use soapUI to connect to Nav. It will create sample requests for you. And you’ll be able to see what request it is doing, and then recreate them literally with any tool that can do http requests and handle appropriate auth that is set on nav instance.

Comment: @Mak Sim I have tried and it does not work either.

Comment: I can’t help you with php. What was the error when you tried soapui?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.soap({
        url: "http://url:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/COMPANY/Page/ws_myws",
        data: {
            user: "user",
            pass: "pass"
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonp_callback",
    crossDomain: true,

        HTTPHeaders: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
            'Server-Protocol':'SOAP'
        },
        success: function (response){
            response = $.format(response.toString(), {method: 'xml' });
            $("#output").text(response);
        }
    })
```

RESPONSE:
http://url/WS/COMPANY/Page/ws_myws net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT